# JavaScript: Both dialog boxes show, even if the user enters incorrectly

Tags: javascript

This is a simple JavaScript/HTML guessing game. The only problem I have is that when the user enters a number/letter other than 1-6, the "error" message should pop-up — and it does, but then the game goes on and it still tells you whether you're a winner or not. This is the code that I have.

```
function jsFunc() {
    var number = Math.ceil (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var guessNum = 0;
    guessNum = document.getElementById("num").value;

    if (isNaN(guessNum) || guessNum < 1 || guessNum > 6) {
        alert ("Must be a number between 1 and 6. Please re-enter!");
    }

    if (number == guessNum)
        alert("Congratulations, You Win!!!");
    else
        alert("Aw, You Lose..");
}
```

Comment: did you try returning after the alert using `return`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add if else to make it work

Please refer snippet

```js
   function jsFunc() {
            var number = Math.ceil (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            var guessNum = 0;

                guessNum = document.getElementById("num").value;
               

            if (isNaN(guessNum) || guessNum < 1 || guessNum > 6) {
                alert ("Must be a number between 1 and 6. Please re-enter!");
            }else if (number == guessNum){
                alert("Congratulations, You Win!!!");
                }
            else{
                alert("Aw, You Lose..");
                }
        }
```

```html
<input id ="num"/> <button  onClick="jsFunc()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing else-if

```
function jsFunc() {
var number = Math.ceil (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var guessNum = 0;

    guessNum = document.getElementById("num").value;

if (isNaN(guessNum) || guessNum < 1 || guessNum > 6) {
    alert ("Must be a number between 1 and 6. Please re-enter!");
}
else if (number == guessNum)
    alert("Congratulations, You Win!!!");
else
    alert("Aw, You Lose..");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (isNaN(guessNum) || guessNum < 1 || guessNum > 6) {
                alert ("Must be a number between 1 and 6. Please re-enter!");
             }

            else if (number == guessNum)
              {
                alert("Congratulations, You Win!!!");
              }
            else
             {
                alert("Aw, You Lose..");
             }
```

You if/else logic needs to be one continuous block. Because in your original code, your second IF get evaluated no matter what!